# Why do I get an error when setting monitor mode if the interface is monitor mode capable?

Tags: permissions, wifi, network-interface, monitoring, wireshark

I have these features on my system:

```
 iw list
Wiphy phy4
    max # scan SSIDs: 10
    max scan IEs length: 255 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x19e7
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            Dynamic SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: No restriction (0x00)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-31
        VHT Capabilities (0x738b7992):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformer
            SU Beamformee
            MU Beamformer
            RX antenna pattern consistency
            TX antenna pattern consistency
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ AP } <= 17, #{ managed } <= 30, #{ monitor } <= 1,
           total <= 17, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match, radar detect widths: { 20 MHz (no HT), 20 MHz, 40 MHz, 80 MHz }

    Supported extended features:
Wiphy phy3
    max # scan SSIDs: 10
    max scan IEs length: 255 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x19e7
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            Dynamic SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: No restriction (0x00)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-31
        VHT Capabilities (0x738ff9fa):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz, 80+80 MHz
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformer
            SU Beamformee
            MU Beamformer
            RX antenna pattern consistency
            TX antenna pattern consistency
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5860 MHz [172] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5870 MHz [174] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5875 MHz [175] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5880 MHz [176] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5890 MHz [178] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5895 MHz [179] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5900 MHz [180] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5905 MHz [181] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5910 MHz [182] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5915 MHz [183] (20.0 dBm)
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ AP } <= 17, #{ managed } <= 30, #{ monitor } <= 1,
           total <= 17, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match, radar detect widths: { 20 MHz (no HT), 20 MHz, 40 MHz, 80 MHz }

    Supported extended features:
```

and:

```
iw dev
phy#4
    Interface wifi1
        ifindex 19
        wdev 0x400000001
        addr 00:03:7f:12:e9:d7
        type AP
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 42949608.96 dBm
phy#3
    Interface ath0
        ifindex 100
        wdev 0x300000050
        addr 2c:27:9e:91:43:d0
        type managed
        channel 36 (5180 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 5190 MHz
        txpower 42949608.96 dBm
    Interface wifi0
        ifindex 18
        wdev 0x300000001
        addr 2c:27:9e:91:43:d0
        type AP
        channel 36 (5180 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 5190 MHz
        txpower 42949608.96 dBm
```

However, when I do:

```
ifconfig ath0 down && iwconfig ath0 mode monitor && ifconfig 
ath0 up
```

I get this error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device ath0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Also, when using `sudo`, I get:

```
-ash: sudo: not found
```

Although I'm in the root user, maybe I have some restrictions in the permissions? Is there anything I can do to get the wireless interfaces in monitor mode?

Comment: If you're the root user there's no need to use `sudo`. Just omit it from any instructions you're following

Comment: thank you @roaima but I'm not using sudo; I've also tried it just in case that was the issue, but I think it's not

Comment: If you're not using `sudo` why did you write, "_Also, when using `sudo`, I get: `-ash: sudo: not found`_"?

Comment: just in case someone suggests I should use sudo :-)